# Returning only Twitter Tweet text in JSON result for Webpage

Tags: php, twitter

I have a webpage in which I wish to return the latest tweet 'text' of a specific user.

I have followed this tutorial here - http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/authenticating-twitter-feed-timeline-oauth/

Setup a Twitter application etc and the relevant code to return a JSON result of the latest tweet. The issue that I have is the array of JSON information returned. I have checked the https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline site for how to restrict this but cannot seem to find it.

Here is an example result returned:

```
> [{"created_at":"Thu Mar 06 02:45:46 +0000
> 2014","id":441404238522875904,"id_str":"441404238522875904","text":"RT
> @womeng: Our own @janetvh shares the story of #womeng + how we choose
> and measure our efforts.
> https:\/\/t.co\/sEXmIwwPAK","source":"TweetDeck<\/a>","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":783214,"id_str":"783214","name":"Twitter","screen_name":"twitter","location":"San
> Francisco, CA","description":"Your official source for news, updates
> and tips from Twitter,
> Inc.","url":"http:\/\/t.co\/5iRhy7wTgu","entities":{"url":{"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/5iRhy7wTgu","expanded_url":"http:\/\/blog.twitter.com\/","display_url":"blog.twitter.com","indices":[0,22]}]},"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":29229772,"friends_count":131,"listed_count":83766,"created_at":"Tue
> Feb 20 14:35:54 +0000
> 2007","favourites_count":26,"utc_offset":-28800,"time_zone":"Pacific
> Time (US &
> Canada)","geo_enabled":true,"verified":true,"statuses_count":1733,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"ACDED6","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/657090062\/l1uqey5sy82r9ijhke1i.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/657090062\/l1uqey5sy82r9ijhke1i.png","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2284174758\/v65oai7fxn47qv9nectx_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2284174758\/v65oai7fxn47qv9nectx_normal.png","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/783214\/1347405327","profile_link_color":"226699","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"F6F6F6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":false,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Thu
> Mar 06 02:08:23 +0000
> 2014","id":441394833148481536,"id_str":"441394833148481536","text":"Our
> own @janetvh shares the story of #womeng + how we choose and measure
> our efforts. https:\/\/t.co\/sEXmIwwPAK","source":"Twitter for
> iPhone<\/a>","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":437698597,"id_str":"437698597","name":"Twitter
> WomEng","screen_name":"womeng","location":"San Francisco,
> CA","description":"Twitter's Women in Engineering
> Group","url":null,"entities":{"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":16019,"friends_count":118,"listed_count":135,"created_at":"Thu Dec 15 18:42:44 +0000
> 2011","favourites_count":26,"utc_offset":-36000,"time_zone":"Hawaii","geo_enabled":true,"verified":true,"statuses_count":290,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2346587762\/6bzyl5e7v13fijy4cs7y_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2346587762\/6bzyl5e7v13fijy4cs7y_normal.png","profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":false,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":76,"favorite_count":118,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"womeng","indices":[37,44]}],"symbols":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/sEXmIwwPAK","expanded_url":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=iPo0KLQ4Ihg&index=6&list=PL8k-xHP7bhnKHc5qJeH5YCdfqgJFiYT2N","display_url":"youtube.com\/watch?v=iPo0KL\u2026","indices":[86,109]}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"janetvh","name":"janet
> van
> huysse","id":74534435,"id_str":"74534435","indices":[8,16]}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"lang":"en"},"retweet_count":76,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"womeng","indices":[49,56]}],"symbols":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/sEXmIwwPAK","expanded_url":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=iPo0KLQ4Ihg&index=6&list=PL8k-xHP7bhnKHc5qJeH5YCdfqgJFiYT2N","display_url":"youtube.com\/watch?v=iPo0KL\u2026","indices":[98,121]}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"womeng","name":"Twitter
> WomEng","id":437698597,"id_str":"437698597","indices":[3,10]},{"screen_name":"janetvh","name":"janet
> van
> huysse","id":74534435,"id_str":"74534435","indices":[20,28]}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"lang":"en"}]
```

Put as code type due to the size of it, but you get the idea.

Ideally I would like the tweet HTML'ified and just the text to display on the page only.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have followed the tutorial:

```
$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

$last_tweet = $tweets[0]->text;
echo $last_tweet; // win \o/
```

by doing this :

```
json_encode($tweets);
```

you change an array (with all user's tweets) into a string...